Copy only tables which are created on 19-Apr-2024 ---> ( 20240419/20240419)
using AZURE DATA FACTORY,
create pipeline using SQL Query
--->IN LOOKUP QUERY :
select name, format(create_date, 'yyyyMMdd') creationdate from sys.tables where cast(create_date as date)= '2024-04-23')

where
----> for each
parameter1: name
parameter2: creationdate
copy: dbo.name
sink:
folder creationdate
filename: name.csv
copy tables LIKE THIS:
NAME                            CREATION DATE
sysdiagrams                 20240423
Customer                    20240423
ProductModel                    20240423
ProductDescription          20240423
Product                         20240423
ProductModelProductDescription  20240423
ProductCategory                 20240423
BuildVersion                    20240423
ErrorLog                    20240423
Address                     20240423
CustomerAddress                 20240423
SalesOrderDetail            20240423
SalesOrderHeader            20240423


You need to use dataset parameters for both source and target datasets to achive your requirement.
First create SQL table dataset. In the parameters section, create a string parameter table_name and use that as @dataset().table_name in the table name like below.


Similarly, create two parameters target_folder and target_filename for the target folder and target filename in the sink dataset and use those in the folder path and file path of the sink dataset like below. Here, for sample I took csv as target file, you can choose it as per your requirement.

Now, in the pipeline, take lookup activity and give the SQL dataset for it. In the parameters give empty string '' and provide your query in the query section.
select name, format(create_date, 'yyyyMMdd') creationdate from sys.tables where cast(create_date as date) = '<your date>';


Next, take a For-Each activity and give the lookup output array @activity('Lookup1').output.value to the for-each expression.
Inside For-loop, take copy activity with above datasets as source and sink. In the source, give @item().table_name to the dataset parameter.

In the sink, give the expressions @item().creationdate and @concat(item().name,'.<file_externsion>') to the dataset parameters target_folder and target_filename respectively.

Now, debug the pipeline and it will give the expected results.

